# Is there a shared word for "word" and "thing" in any language other than Hebrew?

Tags: comparative-linguistics, hebrew, lexical-semantics

The Hebrew word דבר has a dual meaning because it can mean "word/speak" and also "thing." Contemporary Kabbalists use this dual meaning to argue for a metaphysical connection between concrete things and the Hebrew words which refer to those things. One Kabbalist even claimed that he spoke to various linguists and confirmed that in no other language is there a single word that means both "word/speak" and also "thing." Can this claim be verified?

Comment: This isn't the kind of claim that can be verified by speaking to a few linguists, unless between them they have a thorough knowledge of the 7000 or so languages of the world.

Comment: "thing" itself originally referred to a court matter or trial before switching to the issue at hand by metonymy, then becoming a physical object. Not the same but similar...

Comment: @TKR Well we can find a counter example, which a few of us did.

Comment: Seems to be a common set of senses in the ancient languages of the Near East - Aramaic, Hebrew, Armenian…

Answer (score 10):

The Proto-Slavic word [*rěčь](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/r%C4%9B%C4%8D%D1%8C) “speech” (Old Church Slavonic *рѣчь*) has its descendants in all the modern Slavic languages, mostly with the same meaning. But in Polish [*rzecz*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rzecz#Polish) [ʐɛtʂ] and in Ukrainian [*річ*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D1%96%D1%87#Ukrainian) (rič) [ritʂ] the main meaning of the word shifted to “thing” (cf. Polish *rzeczpospolita* “republic”¹, from *rzecz* (“thing”) +‎ *pospolity* (“common”), calque of Latin *rēspūblica* (“public affair”)), while at the same time retaining the old meaning “speech”, although in Polish this latter meaning is considered obsolete and in Ukrainian colloquial.

---

¹ In the 17th century and later the *Kingdom of Poland and the Grand Duchy of Lithuania* a.k.a. *Polish–Lithuanian Commonwealth* was also known as the 'Most Serene Commonwealth of Poland' (Polish: *Najjaśniejsza Rzeczpospolita Polska*, Latin: *Serenissima Res Publica Poloniae*)

Comment: Modern-day Polish has "rzecznik" for "spokesperson".

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki - Yes, but I guess _rzecznik_ is not from the noun _rzecz_, but from the verb [_rzec_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rzec) /ʐɛt͡s/  (“to say”), — ‘the sayer/speaker’ rather than ‘speech man’. In any way, the original root is the same.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki - By the way, where's the stress in _rzeczpospolita_? Some sources say it's on the penult: (_rzeczpospol**i**ta_), others say it's on the antepenultimate syllable, 3rd from the end: (_rzeczposp**o**lita_)...

Comment: Sorry. I am not a professional. Indeed https://fil.ug.edu.pl/wydzial_filologiczny/instytuty/instytut_filologii_polskiej/porady_jezykowe/wymowa?page=1 claims it's 3rd from the end.  But 2nd from end doesn't sound wrong to me either.

Answer (score 10):

Japanese こと *koto* corresponds to both "(abstract) thing, matter" (written 事) and "word" (written 言), although the word for "word" in the modern language is 言葉 *kotoba*, a compound of 言 *koto* + 端 *ha* "extremity".

Answer (score 6):

Aramaic mellṯā has the same two meanings (not just in Jewish dialects, but also in Syriac etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ancient and modern **Armenian** and **Aramaic**, and probably not by coincidence - the link between these sense of *word* and *thing* seems to be common to the ancient literary languages of the Eastern Mediterranean, Mesopotamia and the Armenian Highlands.

[**բան**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D5%A2%D5%A1%D5%B6#Armenian) (`ban`)

> From [Old Armenian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Armenian) [բան](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D5%A2%D5%A1%D5%B6#Old_Armenian) (`ban`); see it for more. The main meaning of բան (ban) in Old Armenian was "word, speech, saying". The sense "thing", which is the only one surviving in modern Armenian, developed from the notion of speech → the subject of speech → the subject itself. Typologically compare Hebrew [⁧דבר⁩](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8#Hebrew) (davar, “word, speech; thing”).

[**ܡܠܬܐ**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%DC%A1%DC%A0%DC%AC%DC%90#Classical_Syriac) (`melləṯā`)

> Learned borrowing from Classical Syriac, from Aramaic [⁧מֵלְּתָא⁩](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%90) (melləṯā); compare Hebrew [מִלָּה](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%9C%D6%B8%D6%BC%D7%94%E2%81%A9) (milá) with the sense of “logos” a semantic loan from Ancient Greek λόγος (lógos).

In modern Armenian, the sense of *word* is preserved and productive in ancient and modern Armenian occupation names ending in [-բան](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%D5%A2%D5%A1%D5%B6) (`-ban`), corresponding to English `-logist` and `-logian`, and concepts derived from them.

They are generally direct calques of ancient Greek occupation names ending in [*-λογος*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%CE%BB%CF%8C%CE%B3%CE%BF%CF%82#Greek) (`-logos`) or modern internationalisms, like [աստվածաբան](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D5%A1%D5%BD%D5%BF%D5%BE%D5%A1%D5%AE%D5%A1%D5%A2%D5%A1%D5%B6) (`astvacaban`) for *theologian* or [կենսաբան](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D5%AF%D5%A5%D5%B6%D5%BD%D5%A1%D5%A2%D5%A1%D5%B6) (`kensaban`) for *biologist*.

Answer (score -2):

In Russian, the word *понятие* can mean a thing, matter or a term for that thing.

In English similar role have words *notion*, *conception*.

Comment: But does it mean ‘word’? _Notion_ and _conception_ do not mean ‘word’.

Comment: Nether do they mean ‘thing’. When someone dies of a brick that fell on their head, you cannot say “a heavy conception crushed their skull”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the Russian понятие can aso mean "a term".

Answer (score -4):

The word "news" can be all three words you mention in Hebrew. Indicating something about intel/in tell. I find as I get older dictionaries can change and spellings can also. I grew up with a temple using Sholom in English and not Shalom but they can use both in some readings today and their awning reads Sholom. Sometimes I find the Hebrew letters change occasionally but it still works.

Comment: Are you suggesting that "intel" is shortened from "in tell"? If so, I'm sorry to disappoint, but it's short for "intelligence", apparently ultimately from Latin "inter + legere"  - "to choose between". The rest of your answer doesn't seem to have much to do with the question.